# Laravel softdeletes on a raw query problem

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Im using `SoftDeletes` in laravel but it retrives all the columns in my database even if it has a `deleted_at` column. Im using a raw query to retrieve the data in my table. Can someone tell me what to do?

Results after i deleted
[image]

my database
[image]

query

```
$products = DB::select(
            "SELECT products.id, products.price, products.product_name, products.description, products.quantity, suppliers.name
             FROM products
             JOIN suppliers ON products.supplier_id = suppliers.id"
             );
```

Model

```
use SoftDeletes;
    protected $fillable = [
        'product_name', 'quantity', 'description' ,'supplier_id', 'price',
    ];

  public function supplier()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Supplier');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a raw query you are bypassing the help of Eloquent which filters against soft deleted rows. So what you need is to add an additional where clause to filter those rows, something like this:

```
SELECT products.id, products.price, products.product_name, products.description, products.quantity, suppliers.name
             FROM products
             JOIN suppliers ON products.supplier_id = suppliers.id
             WHERE products.deleted_at is null
```